# Get Percentages of Tables with Group by

Tags: mysql, count, percentage

I am working on a prediction game for a local league.

A Match is defined by its SPIELTAG (playday) and its MATCH_NR.
A prediction has a Match and a result (ERGA, ERGB)

I have a Table like in this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o4NXPFfzod39LpMaTzqz3r/0

I got the output to count each result per gameday and per match.

```
| SPIELTAG | MATCH_NR | ERGA | ERGB | AMOUNT |
| -------- | -------- | ---- | ---- | ------ |
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 1    | 1      |
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 2    | 2      |
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 3    | 5      |
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 4    | 1      |
| 4        | 2        | 1    | 7    | 1      |
| 4        | 2        | 2    | 7    | 6      |
| 4        | 2        | 3    | 7    | 3      |
```

What i am trying to achieve is, next to the amount column something like

```
| SPIELTAG | MATCH_NR | ERGA | ERGB | AMOUNT | PERC | 
| -------- | -------- | ---- | ---- | ------ | ---- | 
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 1    | 1      | 11.1%| => 1 / 9
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 2    | 2      | 22.2%| => 2 / 9
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 3    | 5      | 55.5%| => 5 / 9
| 4        | 1        | 7    | 4    | 1      | 11.1%| => 1 / 9
| 4        | 2        | 1    | 7    | 1      | 11.1%| => 1 / 9
| 4        | 2        | 2    | 7    | 5      | 55.5%| => 5 / 9
| 4        | 2        | 3    | 7    | 3      | 33.3%| => 3 / 9
```

Where PERC is the percentage of picks per playday SPIELTAG. Basically how often is the Result, the tuple of (ERGA, ERGB) predicted for each match SPIELTAG, MATCH_NR.

I found a post where i can get the percentage over all picks but not restricted  on the gameday,match tuple.

An Example:
Match 1 (Spieltag 4, Match 1) has 9 Predictions.
1x:  7-1
2x: 7-2
5x: 7-3
1x: 7-4
__
9x -> ALL_COUNTS_PER_MATCH

So PERC should be something like 'AMOUNT' / ALL_COUNTS_PER_MATCH.

Comment: I am unable to understand how PERC is logically calculated. Could you explain with a singular example?

Comment: Made an edit. Hope it helps

Comment: What is the 9 you're dividing by? Is it the count of all columns?

Comment: Its the amount of predictions for each Match, so the count all rows with the same SPIELTAG and MATCH_NR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another group by:

```
SELECT `t`.`SPIELTAG` AS `SPIELTAG`,
       `t`.`MATCH_NR` AS `MATCH_NR`,
       `t`.`TEAM_A`   AS `ERGA`,
       `t`.`TEAM_B`   AS `ERGB`,
       count(0)       AS `AMOUNT`,
       COUNT(0) / MAX(A.TOTAL_AMOUNT) -- MIN would also work
FROM `TIPPSPIEL_TIPP` `t`
         JOIN (
    -- Calculate the row count by each different spieltag & match_nr combination
    SELECT `t`.`SPIELTAG`,
           `t`.`MATCH_NR`,
           count(0) AS `TOTAL_AMOUNT`
    FROM `TIPPSPIEL_TIPP` `t`
    GROUP BY `t`.`SPIELTAG`, `t`.`MATCH_NR`
) A USING (SPIELTAG, MATCH_NR)
GROUP BY `t`.`SPIELTAG`, `t`.`MATCH_NR`, `t`.`TEAM_A`, `t`.`TEAM_B`
;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o4NXPFfzod39LpMaTzqz3r/3

Comment: @recklessGreed Edited my answer to explain a little. Anything in particular that you think is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Check this, but will work in Mysql 8, not lower versions

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o4NXPFfzod39LpMaTzqz3r/4

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `t`.`SPIELTAG` AS `SPIELTAG`,
       `t`.`MATCH_NR` AS `MATCH_NR`,
       `t`.`TEAM_A` AS `ERGA`,
       `t`.`TEAM_B` AS `ERGB`,
       COUNT(0) OVER (PARTITION BY `t`.`SPIELTAG`,
                                   `t`.`MATCH_NR`,
                                   `t`.`TEAM_A`,
                                   `t`.`TEAM_B`) AS AMOUNT,
                     COUNT(0) OVER (PARTITION BY `t`.`SPIELTAG`,
                                                 `t`.`MATCH_NR`,
                                                 `t`.`TEAM_A`,
                                                 `t`.`TEAM_B`) / COUNT(CONCAT(SPIELTAG, MATCH_NR)) OVER (PARTITION BY `t`.`SPIELTAG`,
                                                                                                                      `t`.`MATCH_NR`) AS match_count
FROM `TIPPSPIEL_TIPP` `t`
```

Comment: Works on my local db but not on the servers. Cannot update the server. Therefore not the accepted but also working answer!